# RealBasic app crashes on writeline

Tags: permissions, crash, realbasic

I have an Mac RB app that crashes when I write a line to a TextOutputStream on the user's preferences.
The write operation works great when the user is the admin, but any other user crashes.
This made me think it's a permission issue, so I tried changing permission, without luck.

The error is:
"An exception of class NilObjectException was not handled. The operation must shut down"

Any help from you amazing people would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Here's the code:

```
Dim TableString as String
Dim fileStream As TextOutputStream
Dim File as FolderItem

File = SpecialFolder.SharedPreferences.Child("FileName.txt") 

TableString = TranslationTableToString

fileStream=File.CreateTextFile

// This didn't help:
//File.permissions= &o777

// This line Breaks:
fileStream.WriteLine TableString
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what version of RB you are using, but for any reasonably current version, the syntax you should be using is:

```
fileStream = TextOutputStream.Create(File)
```

Which you should wrap in a Try/Catch to get this:

```
Try
  fileStream = TextOutputStream.Create(File)
  fileStream.WriteLine(TableString)
Catch e As IOException
  MsgBox("Error Code: " + Str(e.ErrorNumber))
End Try
```

e.ErrorNumber will contain an OS-specific error code to help you pinpoint the problem.

http://docs.realsoftware.com/index.php/IOException

Comment: Thanks! Will implement as soon as back from vacation :-)